# Is it possible to get a "potential" stack trace for a method at compile time?

Tags: java, eclipse

So, I've got a routine that can be called from about four different functions. What I want to do is walk up the possible routes that a this routine could have been called from.

I'm using Eclipse. I'm thinking this must be somewhat possible as I know I can do this by hand, albeit slowly.

Comment: You want to do that for debug purpose ?

Comment: Essentially, yeah, for debugging, but naturally, I'm looking to do this at compile time because at run-time is going to be arduous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In eclipse, right click on the method name and select 'Open call hierarchy'.  Usually it's associated with 'Ctrl+Alt+H'.

Answer (score 1):

put your cursor on the method name and hit `ctrl-alt-h` for the calling methods

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, had to choose one.